# Get a list of elements into separated arrays

Tags: python, xpath

Hello fellow developer out there,

I'm new to Python & I need to write a web scraper to catch info from Scholar Google.

I ended up coding this function to get values using Xpath:

```
thread = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,(" %s" % exp))
xArray = []

for t in thread:
    if not atr:
        xThread = t.text 
    else:
        xThread = t.get_attribute('href')

    xArray.append(xThread)

    return xArray
```

I don't know if it's a good or a bad solution. So, I humbly accept any suggestions to make it work better.

Anyway, my actual problem is that I am getting all authors name from the page I am scraping and what I really need are the names, grouped by result. 
When I ask to print the results I wish I could have something like this:

```
[[author1, author2,author 3],[author 4,author 5,author6]]
```

What am I getting right now is:

```
[author1,author3,author4,author5,author6]
```

The structure is as follows:

```
<div class="gs_a">
    LR Hisch,
<a href="/citations?user=xuBuLKYAAAAJ&amp;hl=es&amp;oi=sra">AM Gobin</a>
    ,AR Lowery,
<a href="/citations?user=ziumTX0AAAAJ&amp;hl=es&amp;oi=sra">F Tam</a>
 ... -Annals of biomedical ...,2006 - Springer
</div>
```

And the same structure is repetead all over the page for different documents and authors.

And this is the call to the function I explained earlier:

```
authors = (clothoSpins(".//*[@class='gs_a']//a"))
```

Which gets me the entire list of authors.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the page you're scraping it's going to be largely impossible for us to answer this question.

Comment: One important thing to learn about Python: it does not have arrays, the structure you are talking about is a list. Might look similar, but there are major differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic (used selenium in the below code but update it as per your need).

**Logic:**

```
url = "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C21&q=python&btnG="
driver.get(url)
# get the authors and add to list
listBooks = []
books = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='gs_a']")
for bookNum in books:
    auths = []
    authors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[@class='gs_a'])[%s]/a|(//div[@class='gs_a'])[%s]/self::*[not(a)]"%(bookNum+1,bookNum+1))
    for author in authors:
        auths.append(author.text)
    listBooks.append(auths)
```

**Output:**

```
[['F Pedregosa', 'G Varoquaux', 'A Gramfort'], ['PD Adams', 'PV Afonine'], ['TE Oliphant'], ['JW Peirce'], ['S Anders', 'PT Pyl', 'W Huber'], ['MF Sanner'], ['S Bird', 'E Klein'], ['M Lutz - 2001 - books.google.com'], ['G Rossum - 1995 - dl.acm.org'], ['W McKinney - … of the 9th Python in Science Conference, 2010 - pdfs.semanticscholar.org']]
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on it. Actually I need a generic solution. I am fetching lots of information (title, publisher, year, etc.)

Comment: `for bookNum in range(len(books))` can be simplified to `for bookNum in books:`. No need for `range(len(<list>))`.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out @DmitriyZub, the answer is updated now.